# AWS Route 53: How to point two load balancers to same subdomain?

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, load-balancing, amazon-route53, amazon-elb

I have two load balancers on different regions, each with their own EC2 instances. Each EC2 instance has a deployment of the same app.

I would like to know if it is possible to create a DNS record, that distributes traffic among the two load balancers or instances?

Otherwise I would like to know how to distribute traffic on my subdomain `my-subdomain.domain.com` among instances on different regions: ASIA-PACIFIC, US-EAST, US_WEST

Thanks in advance

Comment: "if it is possible to create a DNS record, that distributes traffic among the two load balancers or instances?", No, not with standard DNS. `SRV` records could help in that, but only as long as clients are using them and browsers are not. Other than that your question is offtopic here as not related to programming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checkout AWS global Accelerator. It is ideal for your use case. It will give you public ips and you can then point your subdomain at it